# Intermittent network drop-outs and Ping packet loss

Tags: networking, internet

For the past few weeks, I've been dealing with issues on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS laptop.  Essentially, my laptop disconnects intermittently - it will stay connected for about 20 seconds, then drop out for about a minute (it still says it's connected, it just doesn't receive anything over network), then connect again for 30 seconds, and so on.  I can tell that it's a problem with the laptop, as no other device on the network is having these issues and the packet loss exists regardless of whether I ping the router (at 192.168.1.1) or an external DNS server.  As I have a Wi-Fi extender hooked up with a separate network SSID, I'm able to force a re-connect by swapping whether I'm connected to the router or the extender, but this too will drop out after about a minute or less.

I'm not really sure which logs are relevant or how I can determine whether this is a hardware or a software issue, so I'd appreciate any help available.  Thanks.

Edit: I, a fool, forgot briefly that my computer is set up for dual-boot with Windows.  After some brief testing, I was able to determine that the intermittent network drop-outs *do not occur* on Windows, while they do on Ubuntu - thus, it seems likely to me that the issue is software related.

I also followed the advice of one of the comments, and I was able to get some information about my wireless setup.  [Here's a paste of the output of that wireless-info script](https://pastebin.com/5XpEizpc), but nothing appears immediately wrong to my untrained eye.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator Well, that's helpful information, and I'll be amending my question with the output of the script in the first question once I get it uploaded, but it doesn't "answer" my question by a long shot